# How to handle git bisect with external code causing failure

Tags: git

I am having an issue where a code change between two versions of the linux kernel is causing an issue. While using `git bisect`, I find that I can't narrow down the original problem because of an unrelated problem in the linux kernel (graphics corruption) that makes it impossible to track down the original issue.

With `git bisect`, there are two choices: good or bad; and in this case I can't mark the patch 'good' because of the unrelated issue.

Do I mark that patch 'bad' according to git bisect or do I do something else?

Comment: Maybe disable the part of the kernel that is causing the corruption if possible, e.g. run without X?

Comment: I don't see how that can be done. The bug is probably related to graphics stack and X activity specifically. I don't know any other way to manifest it other than just doing my regular daily work, heavy browser work, video calls etc.

Comment: Ok, just a suggestion.

Comment: My troubles may have actually been caused by the GCC related compilation bug that Linus recently fixed. Haven't had any of the symptoms afterwards.

Comment: This, IIRC https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/commit/Makefile?id=2062afb4f804afef61cbe62a30cac9a46e58e067

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git` doesn't force you to use the commit it gives you. With `git reset --hard othercommit` you can choose another commit to test and continue bisecting from. With `git bisect skip` you can let `git` choose a different commit automatically (and mark the problematic commit as skipped so it won't be chosen again). You can also mark a range of commits for skipping, the man page has the information.

Of course you can always apply a patch after bisect gives you a commit if you happen to have a fix for the problem that prevents you from testing that commit.